# Interpretation of Kazhdan T property cohomologically

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-cohomology

$\newcommand{\triv}{\mathit{triv}}$A group $G$ has property $T$ if $\triv$ is isolated in the space of unitary representations with the Fell topology.

In general, we heuristically have $H^1(G,Ad(V))$ (where $Ad$ is the kernel of $V \otimes V^* \to triv$) is the tangent space to the representation $V$ in the space of representations.

Thus, I'd expect property $T$ is about $H^1(G,\triv) = 0$.

Instead, I've seen in the literature that the $T$ property for a given representation $V$ (i.e., the existence of compact $K \subset G, \epsilon$ uniformly blocking invariant vectors) is equivalent to $H^1(G,V) = 0$.

How does this align with the tangent space intuition?

Edit-

I am rightfully told that I am completely wrong, but I'm okay with that. I'm trying to understand why the heuristic fails, and what is thus the true reason we use $H^1(G,V)$? How does it relate with the trivial representation being isolated.

Comment: The Property $H^1(G,\mathrm{triv})$ is much weaker since it just means $\mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathbf{R})=0$. For $\sigma$-compact locally compact groups Property T means $H^1(G,\pi)=0$ for every representation $\pi$.

Comment: Your heuristics is wrong even in the finite-dimensional case.

Comment: The $(2,3,7)$ triangle group is probably the easiest example of a group with $H^1(G,triv)=0$ but without property T.

Comment: @HJRW If you really want the "easiest", I'd say (among f.g. groups) the infinite dihedral group. Or, among countable groups, infinite locally finite ones.

Comment: @YCor: I’m not certain what coefficients we are allowed to use. With coefficients in a field of characteristic 0, yes, $D_\infty$ will do.

Comment: @HJRW in the context of Kazhdan's Property T, it's complex unitaries reps. So $H^1(G,\mathrm{triv})$ means $\mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathbf{C})=0$. For $G$ discrete group it just means the abelianization is torsion. More generally for $G$ locally compact it means the Hausdorff abelianization is an increasing union of compact open subgroups (e.g. $G=\mathbf{Q}_p$ satisfies this).

Comment: @YCor As you say I'm definitely wrong, but I'm trying to understand why. How should we be interpreting $H^1(G,V)$?

Comment: Even in the finite-dimensional case, your heuristics are still muddled: What you described now is the complexified Zariski tangent space to the character variety/scheme of $SU(V)$-representations when $(V,\rho)$ is an irreducible and finite dimensional special unitary representation of $G$.

Comment: Please, include the references to the claim that "you have seen in the literature." Most likely you misunderstood what was written.

Comment: @MoisheKohan See (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.06517.pdf). I talked about exactly the zariski tangent space as you did. I believe it should sorta work for infinite representations as well